# Is it possible to inject a controller to DOM in AngularJS?

Tags: controller, angularjs, inject

I am relatively new to angularjs, and what I wanna do is to create a ngView-like component.
so there is a very important process is to inject a controller to DOM.
suppose we have a DOM,

```
<div>
    <span>Name: {{name}}</span>
</div>
```

and a controller,

```
function InjectedController($scope) {  
   $scope.name = "Leo Yuan";  
}
```

What I wanna do is to inject controller "InjectedController" into division,
I tried to write code like ngView does,
$("div").contents().data('$ngControllerController', InjectedController);
but it still didn't work, something wrong?

Comment: I think I know what makes it not work, post the reason here, maybe it would be helpful for some newbies to avoid this.    
$("div").contents().data('$ngControllerController', InjectedController);  
the code above is just fine, what really causes this issue is the inproper usage of service $compile, we can not compile the whole element in directive definition, but only compile the .childNodes, so that we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves.

Comment: Sorry but you shouldn't inject your controller in the DOM.
Please explain what you're trying to achieve first

Comment: @FlorianF My scenario is to create a directive called myView, which will displays many views inside, and each view has a controller and a model, so I can create a multi-page viewer without reloading the page.
Is it bad practice?

Comment: Using ng-switch and ng-include will allow you to do something similar

Comment: Because the requirement always changes, so we have to create our own directive. Could u tell me what's the side effect of injecting controller?

Comment: @LeoYuan88袁力皓 What exactly does not work?  What do you see?

Comment: You'll notice that ng-view also creates a new scope for the controller.  Are you doing this too?  And remember you then have to tear it down when you are finished too.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by including the controller directly into the HTML. Make sure to have this HTML stored as a template or a variable and then load it as a string.

```
<div data-ng-controller="%%controller%%">
  <span>Name: {{name}}</span>
</div>
```

The replace the %%controller%% part with whatever controller you want using JavaScript.

Then either have that run directly or compile that HTML by itself

```
var templateHTML = "..."; //either download it with XHR or make it an inline template
templateHTML = templateHTML.replace('%%controller%%', injectedController);

//inject the $compile service into the function body
//grab the scope if it's not already there
$scope = $scope || angular.element(document).scope();

//this should run the controller automatically
$compile(templateHTML)($scope);
```